# Custom Boolean values on a Report using Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have created a report that accepts a boolean value as a paramerter. However I wish to present the option as values differrnt than true or false.

So I set up some default values and in my preview window I got a nice drop down containing my custom values. However when I deploy this to my server the nice drop down is replaced by the default radio button with the values True or false.

How can i get the custom values to work on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work. What I did was change the paramenter type to string instead of boolean, set up the default values as before and it now works.
It seems that the reporting server can cast the string to a boolean for you.

I'm not that happy with this fix as I am sure it can be done leaving the parameter as a boolean but it with work for now i guess.